EF Core - Owned type is null even though the change tracker has its entry loaded
I'm trying to configure an aggregate root User that have a nullable value object ChangePasswordCode. When I call _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync in the repository, I receive a User object with a null ChangePasswordCode even though the data exists in the database.
Here are the codes:
public class User : AggregateRoot<UserId>
{
    private readonly List<Ban> _bans = [];

    public Name Name { get; private set; }

    public Email Email { get; private set; }

    public Password Password { get; private set; }

    public DepartmentId DepartmentId { get; private set; }

    public Roles Roles { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Ban> Bans => _bans.AsReadOnly();

    public ChangePasswordCode? ChangePasswordCode { get; private set; }

#pragma warning disable CS8618
    private User() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618

    private User(
        UserId id,
        Name name,
        Email email,
        Password password,
        DepartmentId departmentId,
        Roles roles) : base(id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        DepartmentId = departmentId;
        Roles = roles;
    }
    ...
}

public class ChangePasswordCode : ValueObject
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public DateTime ExpiryTime { get; private set; }

    public ChangePasswordCode(string value, DateTime expiryTime)
    {
        Value = value;
        ExpiryTime = expiryTime;
    }
    ...
}

internal class UserConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    ...
    private void ConfigureUsersTable(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        ...

        builder.OwnsOne(u => u.ChangePasswordCode);
        ...

Here is the DbContextSnapshop:
b.OwnsOne("Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.ChangePasswordCode", "ChangePasswordCode", b1 =>
    {
        b1.Property<Guid>("UserId")
            .HasColumnType("uuid");

        b1.Property<DateTime>("ExpiryTime")
            .HasColumnType("timestamp with time zone");

        b1.Property<string>("Value")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("text");

        b1.HasKey("UserId");

        b1.ToTable("Users");

        b1.WithOwner()
            .HasForeignKey("UserId");
    });

b.Navigation("ChangePasswordCode");

Here is where the issue happens:
internal class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IdearDbContext _context;

    public UserRepository(IdearDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<User?> GetByIdAsync(UserId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id, cancellationToken);

        return user; // user.ChangePasswordCode is null here
    }

I have tried checking the change tracker debug view to see if the data is actually retrieved correctly and the debug view is:
User {Id: Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.UserId} Unchanged
    Id: 'Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.UserId' PK
    DepartmentId: 'Domain.DepartmentAggregate.ValueObjects.DepartmentId' FK
    Email: 'Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.Email'
    Name: 'Domain.Shared.ValueObjects.Name'
    Password: 'Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.Password'
    Roles: 'Admin'
  Bans: []
  ChangePasswordCode: <null>
ChangePasswordCode {UserId: Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.UserId} Unchanged
    UserId: 'Domain.UserAggregate.ValueObjects.UserId' PK FK
    ExpiryTime: '11/20/2024 9:31:31 AM'
    Value: 'B20BB3'

It's weird that the ChangePasswordCode is actually loaded and tracked, but for some reason, it's not attached to the User entry.
I have found a similar question here, and tried out the suggestion but it's still null. I have also tried switching to non-nullable ChangePasswordCode property, it does make the field required in the database, but it's still null when mapped to User object.

TL;DR - I implement the GetHashCode method wrong for ValueObject.
After creating a different project to test out the User and ChangePasswordCode, I find out that the problem lies in the UserId value object as it works fine when I use Guid as the primary key. At that time, I suspect that the change tracker may compare the 2 UserId in User and ChangePasswordCode entries and somehow doesn't match the 2. So the problem could be in the Equals and GetHashCode method that I implement for ValueObject.
By placing breakpoints in debug mode, I find out that the change tracker indeed calls the GetHashCode first before the Equals and it returns 2 different hash codes for the same UserId. I fix the GetHashCode method and it works now.
